# React native webview partial page load

Tags: webview, react-native

In a react native component I have requirement to load some specific content from a web page, Can we load a specific content section of third party web page to react-native webview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It done with iFrame, have rendered partial page in iFrame and then provided source as html in webview.
`<WebView ref={'webview'} automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
              scrollEnabled={false}
              html={htmlCode} />`